# Android - SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to build an app that will use an SQLite database. My question is once the database is created, will all data still be there once the app is closed, i.e.: the database won't be overwritten when the app is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, as a developer are the only one who have access to this database, thus it is only your code which will be allowed to change the state or content of this database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data will remain there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data will remain in your application when you close the application. When you run the application the database create in the application.

But yes, if the user uninstalls, the application then user will lose the application. On the other hand, if you want to save the data when the application is uninstalled, then it's better to create the database in SDCard.

Answer (score 0):

The data will remain there because of your default create method. There is a status code. You can use SQLScout http://www.idescout.com/ to visualize the table and watch its change step by step.